# unable to set custom font in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsmutableattributedstring

I am unable to set custom font in `NSMutableAttributedString`

But when setting font to System it's working fine.
Here is my code:

```
 NSString *str=@"my attributed text";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
    UIFont *customFont =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Play-Regular" size:13.0];
    [attString addAttributes:@{
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:111.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:26.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                               NSFontAttributeName: customFont,
                               } range:NSMakeRange(0,str.length)];
```

I am unable to set custom font in UISearchbar.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Play-Regular" size:13.0]}];
```

Although I have successfully added Play font.

But it working fine when setting

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]}];
```

Comment: Can you print stack of customFont. May be its not picking your correct font.

Comment: Check your font name using      NSArray *allfamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
    for (NSString *familyName in allfamilies)
        NSLog(@"fonts %@ \nin family %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName],familyName);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedstring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My text"];
    [attributedstring addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor myColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.selectedbanner.bannerTitle.length)];
    [attributedstring addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:fontsize] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.selectedbanner.bannerTitle.length)];
    myTextField.attributedText = attributedstring;
```

Cross check your font name and make sure you've added that font to your project bundle